# Maintain a bottom view like a footer in all app interface swift2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

Sorry for my English. I'm new with iOS and I wonder how to create view controller and fixed it in the footer of every interface in the app. The view is some kind of a media controller.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLcLc.jpg)

Comment: Use the toolbar in navigation controller. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2312496/2710486).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using storyboard, drag a controller from widgets library and do the following steps.

1. Add a view at the bottom of the controller view and customise however the format you want.
2. Drag a `ContainerView` from the widgets library and add it just above the bottom view (added in step 1)
3. Now define as many controllers as your application requires.
4. Set segue identifiers to each and every controllers segue.
5. Use following code to in your root controller

   ```
   [-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if(\[segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"controller1"\]) {

   } else if (\[segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"controller2"\]) {

   }
   ```

[image: Shows how to set segue identifier]
[image: Shows how storyboard looks like after adding container view with footer]